# check that x in list.remove(y) in one line

Tags: python, list

What is the way to make list.remove() behave as a list on this same line to perform operations such as element searches or indexing (i.e. make iterable or subscriptable)? E.g. I am trying the above which are not working.

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
'a' in myList.remove('b')
'a' in list(myList.remove('c'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    'a' in list(myList.remove('c'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Edit after first responses.

What I am trying to do is the following.

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if 'a' in myList:
    myList.remove('b')
    if 'c' in myList:
         ...
```

So I am wondering if I could this in the same statement

Comment: `myList.remove('b'); 'a' in myList`

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is two different statements on the same line. I would not be able to use it in an if statement for example. E.g. `if a == 3 and  'a' in list(myList.remove('c'))` . Again, my code example returns an error of course

Comment: @Tony What is the real problem?

Comment: Do you need to have the original list mutated after the operation is complete?  why is there a requirement for a one-liner?

Comment: @Elmex80s That I am trying in the same if statement to check if a value is  in a list and then if another value is in the same list after removing an element.

Comment: Why can't you use a nested `if`?

Comment: @Tony in that case try this: `if 'a' in your_list and 'b' in set(your_list) - {'c'}:`

Comment: Does the list have duplicates though? If so, list.remove() only removes the first one; `aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz'];

aList.remove('xyz');
print "List : ", aList` 

prints: 

`List :  [123, 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz']`

Comment: @Elmex80s can you please post your last comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted one

Comment: @Tony did that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will do

```
if 'a' in your_list and 'c' in set(your_list) - {'b'}:
    # some code
    pass
```

I am using `sets` here. Note that after the statement `'b'` still will be in the list.

But from a logical point of view I prefer to test for this

```
{'a', 'c'} <= set(your_list) and 'b' != 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove` edits the list in place and returns None, so what you're doing won't work. You need a function that returns a *new* list with that element removed. If you really need a one-liner:

```
'a' in [x for x in myList if x is not 'b']
```

Comment: Variant: ```any('a' == thing for thing in myList if thing != 'b')```

Comment: Also, this is not equivalent if the list has duplicates, but in that case I'm quite sure there is no one-liner (or at least not a pythonic one)

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove()` function does **not** return anything.

So you can check in two steps:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

myList.remove('b')

if 'a' in myList:
  #Some logic
```

Comment: `list.remove()` returns `None`

Comment: So it doesn't return anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can quickly check if `b` is in the list and remove it first

```
myList.remove('b') if 'b' in myList else None
```

then using:

```
'a' in myList
```

To check if `'a'` is in the list (with remove `'b'`)

Comment: That does **not** answer the question I think.

Comment: Ah shoot, that's true. I'll quickly change it